# Reference C #define from runtime parameters

Tags: c, macros

I have a list of #define that describes a set of addresses:

```
#define DMA1_Stream0        ((DMA_Stream_TypeDef *) DMA1_Stream0_BASE)
#define DMA1_Stream1        ((DMA_Stream_TypeDef *) DMA1_Stream1_BASE)
#define DMA1_Stream2        ((DMA_Stream_TypeDef *) DMA1_Stream2_BASE)
#define DMA1_Stream3        ((DMA_Stream_TypeDef *) DMA1_Stream3_BASE)
```

(this is from a CMSIS header) 
and a function that should use one of them depending on the given parameters like:

```
void initDMAStream(uint8_t controller, uint8_t stream)
{
    DMA[controller]_Stream[stream]->CR = 0xdadadada;
    // etc...
}
```

I tried using a macro like

```
#define DMA_STREAM(c, s) DMA ## c ## _Stream ## s
```

but it's not working because it will replace `c` and `s` with the names of the function parameters, not with their values.

Is there some way to do this in C?

Comment: What's wrong using either a `switch` or a table?

Comment: ... or an array? Macro "solutions" are evil.

Comment: Make the argument DMA_Stream_TypeDef*.  And use the macro when you call it.

Comment: Macros are expanded at compile time, therefore their expansions cannot be dependent on anything not known until runtime, such as the values of variables.

Comment: at Olaf, Weather Vane i was trying to avoid remapping them, maybe there was a cleaner solution.     at Hans Passant no because my code itnterface should be separated by the underlying CMIS API.    at John Bollinger i think this is the definitive answer

Comment: This comment system is a mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to mix run-time and compile-time evaluation in an unholy way. In particular, you are trying to use run-time information at compile time.

You can make this work by throwing the compile-time constants into an array, and indexing into it at run-time. For example, set up the array as

`DMA_Stream_TypeDef * DMAstreams[][4] = {
    {DMA0_Stream0, DMA0_Stream1, DMA0_Stream2, DMA0_Stream3},
    {DMA1_Stream0, DMA1_Stream1, DMA1_Stream2, DMA1_Stream3},
    // ...
    };`

and access it with

```
DMAstreams[controller][stream]
```

at run-time.

Comment: Yes, now i have the confirm that this is the only way